# I have files in the TxR folder that I want to delete but cant

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

The files in the TxR folder are (REGTRANS-MS Files and BLF Files) The files in the TxR folder weren't notepads at first.

The files in the TxR folder:
[image: The files in the TxR folder]

Comment: The solution may be as simple as I wrote about here for a similar solution but you'd omit and not use the last line of `RD /S /Q "%Folder%"` but set the value of the `Folder=` variable to equal the path which contains the file. Otherwise look over the section named **Further Notable Items** for more information what the issue may be.